# How to restore crumpled paperbacks?

Tags: books

I accidentally crushed a paperback book by putting my laptop in my backpack on top of it, and now the back cover is crumpled and folded.

What's the best way to restore the book quickly and effectively, if such a way exists?

~ I've tried the usual method of placing the book on a flat surface under a ton of weight overnight, but the folds still persist. What can I do?

Comment: A photo would be really helpful, to get the idea of how severe the damage is.

Comment: There is now a similar question on Literature - https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/25278/99

Answer (score 1):

I've ironed paper before, with an electric iron on low heat.  It works pretty well.  But without seeing a photo of your book, I'm not sure how well that would work or if it would cause any damage.

Comment: This is a pretty good method, I used to add some water before putting iron box, only on cheking if it is not hand written.